# Correct way to write one generic methods for two similar methods?

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core

I have 2 models (EndUser and  EndUserServicesDTO having similar logic, but exist on two different layers)

```
public class EndUserServicesDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string RetypePassword { get; set; }
}

public class AppDeveloperServicesDTO : EndUserServicesDTO
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAdress { get; set; }
    public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }
    public string CompanyPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string CompanyWebSite { get; set; }
}
```

and I have 2 methods in different repositories

```
  private readonly IMongoUOWRepositoryGeneric<EndUser> _userManager;

 public async Task<bool> AddAsync(EndUserServicesDTO userServicesDTO)
    {
        EndUser user = _mapper.Map<EndUser>(userServicesDTO);

        user.PasswordHash = PBKDF2Hasher.HashPassword(userServicesDTO.Password);

        await _userManager.Clients.AddAsync(user);

        return true;
    }



 private readonly IMongoUOWRepositoryGeneric<AppDeveloper> _developerManager;

public async Task<bool> AddAsync(AppDeveloperServicesDTO developerServicesDTO)

    {
        AppDeveloper developer = _mapper.Map<AppDeveloper>(developerServicesDTO);

        developer.PasswordHash = PBKDF2Hasher.HashPassword(developerServicesDTO.Password);

        await _developerManager.Clients.AddAsync(developer);

        return true;
    }
```

both methods have same functionality to add, but being used for different models. Can you please guide me to write same generic method for both keeping the exact scenario in mind.

**What I've tried so far**

leads to `EndUser` class but if I do that, I delete the company properties in `Developer model` and save it without it, otherwise i can't use the `.PasswordHash` for property `Password` and I have no idea how do this using generic method.

Comment: Are you going to have more and more of these? to be honest, if you've only got 2 examples, I'd leave it "as is" - it is going to be *more* work to create the infrastructure to allow this to work in a generic way

Comment: I work to perspective, and now i do it for myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole changes should be like this

```
 public async Task<bool> AddAsync<T>(T dto) where T : IPassword        
 {
     var data = _mapper.Map<T>(dto);

     data.PasswordHash = PBKDF2Hasher.HashPassword(data.Password);

     await _developerManager.Clients.AddAsync(data);

     return true;
  }

  public interface IPassword 
  {
     string Password { set; get; }
     string PaswordHash { set; get; }  
  }

  public class EndUserServicesDTO : IPassword
  {
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
     public string Role { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
     public string RetypePassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppDeveloperServicesDTO : EndUserServicesDTO, IPassword
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyAdress { get; set; }
        public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }
        public string CompanyPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string CompanyWebSite { get; set; }
    }
```

New version based of new requirements:

```
 public class ClientRepository<T> 
    {
        private readonly IMongoUOWRepositoryGeneric<T> _manager;
        readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ClientRepository(IMongoUOWRepositoryGeneric<T> manager, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _manager = manager;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<bool> AddAsync<U>(U dto) where U : IPassword
        {
            dto.PaswordHash = PBKDF2Hasher.HashPassword(dto.Password);
            T data = _mapper.Map<T,U>(dto);               

            await _manager.Clients.AddAsync(data);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No need for IPassword on AppDeveloperServicesDTO ? as it already inherits from EndUserServicesDTO

Comment: yeah it is possible  using only EndUserServicesDTO as generic condition instead IPassword interface (actually it is easiest way and my first thought)   but it  narrows using of generic method only for classes derived from EndUserServicesDTO. Using interface is more "generic".

Comment: I edit the question. I forgot the main thing, sorry!!!!, it about password hash. For me important how create with generic EndUser or AppDeveloper classes because i will create from `private readonly IMongoUOWRepositoryGeneric<EndUser> _userManager;` to `private readonly IMongoUOWRepositoryGeneric<T> _userManager;` need to write from dto to app developer or end user where i should hash the password and send it to create new client. Sorry for my fail !.

                           and in future i will use to update the fields company and need to universal example, which i can't think

Comment: You could just add PaswordHash property to interface too. that is why interfaces exist. Also I think  U and T should be the same in your repository  class. also about generic condition

Comment: @Andrey Adjusted class has been added  to post based on new provided details

Comment: it can't be same because all the my data access layer is generic, and should have the `EndUser` or `AppDeveloper` in the end. And this is the reason why i write T and U.

Comment: you limit T by IPassword, how i write `Enduser` or `Appdeveloper` if T can be only IPassword

Comment: Actually yes but db classes probably generated automatically I have added workaround for avoid changes in generated db classes. It means that PaswordHash should exist in db entity too but it is not required property now.

Comment: i edit all my chain for generic, and i doen't know how realize this idea, it save me big part of code!, and T should be 1 of both Dal entity.

Comment: I have replaced dto.PaswordHash = PBKDF2Hasher.HashPassword(dto.Password); part of code. That could resolve issue.

Comment: Task AddAsync<T>(T data) {} that is entity adding method. Could you specify part of code where exactly you need other generic method  ?

Comment: thank you, register both, i spend time to create controller with configuration, i use it in controller. it simples crud system to add user or other models info to db

Comment: if your repository(DataContext , MongoUOWRepository or others)  allows managing tables with generic type it is not problem at all create CRUD system based on  generic entities. I hope that helped.